# Accept Post request to nodejs from django

Tags: python, node.js, django, express, python-requests

I am making a post request from django to nodejs

```
v = {}
v['id'] = 'test'
y=requests.post('http://localhost:3000',params=v)
```

How can I parse this data in nodejs? Below is my code, but it shows undefined.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.id)  //this shows Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    res.send('hello')
})
```

Comment: If this worked for you as you have mentioned in your comment, would you be so kind as to mark it as correct. thanks

Answer (score 0):

note that with python-requets the POST verb expects a dictionary as `data`

```
v = {}
v['id'] = 'test'
y=requests.post('http://localhost:3000',data=v)
```

params is generally used by the get verb. Having said that I am not sure why you want to connect django and node in this way. Wouldn't it be easier to write the entire thing in one or the other?

Have you enabled the body parser?

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

Comment: done but still not working i am doing this because of data intensive task which nodejs can handle in better way asynchronously

Comment: I am not an expert on express but have you enabled the body parser?